# Given a Rails timestamp, how can I use JavaScript to determine how many days old the timestamp is?

Tags: javascript

Rails provides a timestamp like follows: 2012-12-21T01:09:32Z

How can I use JavaScript to determine how many days old the timestamp is?

Thanks

Comment: The idea being if the timestamp from rails is determined by JavaScript to be older than 7 days do X. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `new Date('2012-12-21T01:09:32Z')` to turn the string into a Date object. Then use simple arithmetic:

```
var dateStr = '2012-12-21T01:09:32Z',
daysAgo = (new Date() - new Date(dateStr)) / 86400 / 1000;

if (daysAgo > 7) {
    // more than 7 days ago
}
```

You may want to use `Math.floor(daysAgo)` or `Math.ceil(daysAgo)` to round the results down or up, depending on your situation.